# Get Facebook User Access Token without user login in Graph API 2.2?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

Given my app has been authorized once by the user, will it be able to get new access tokens without requiring the user to log in again?

If yes how can it be done? (preferably in Node.js)

All other answers I found seem to refer to old versions of the API.

Comment: Remember also that the moment a user **changes their password** all their **user tokens expire** - even those with the maximum lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

No, User Access Tokens are valid for a very short time, and you can only extend them to 60 days. After that, the user MUST visit the App again. You can NEVER get User Tokens without user interaction. This was not even possible with older API versions. There was only an `offline_access` permission some years ago.

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

The new API gives Facebook users more security control by allowing the apps provider to set the expiration of the token to the maximum of 60 days. So, as from I know, there is no way for the user to authorize the token just once and use it forever.